What is the difference between a Source block and a Fenced block in AsciiDoc?
The title says it all.  I have been reading through all of the documentation I can find and I can't  find any distinction between the two.

I think that one is AsciiDoc and the other is Markdown. It's just that Asciidoctor (one of the AsciiDoc processor tools) supports some Markdown syntax.

@RichardSmith That was the clue I needed.  Not much to it but that's the correct answer.
